# Многопоточный парсинг сайтов

Tags: java, многопоточность, kotlin

Теоретический вопрос - как грамотно реализовать в kotlin (или хотя бы Java) следующее:
У меня есть лист с каким-то количеством ссылок (например, 20)
Есть класс, который должен получать ссылку, обрабатывать ее, и если ссылка нас устроила, возвращать какие-то данные (допустим, нужные места со страницы) и на этом выполнение программы заканчивается.
Хочется сделать так, чтобы проверялось сразу несколько ссылок, хотя бы от 3 до 5.
Как это сделать? Есть очень некрасивое решение, где в цикле while пересоздаются треды.
Нужен совет профессионалов)

Comment: https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/coroutines.html

Comment: Подсказки: Kotlin -> coroutines, Java -> thread pool. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html